# AndroidStudio/Gradle : How to manage dependencies on separated local project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I try to have 2 independent projects in AndroidStudio :

/some_root/Lib1

/some_root/Project1 ('app')

The build lifecycle of the 2 projects are separated (2 gits, 2 jenkins target, ...) and Lib1 is used by some other projects.

- When I build Lib1, I want to generate a versioned aar.
- When I build Project1, that depends on Lib1, I want to generate an apk WITHOUT rebuilding my lib each time (aar installed on local maven or nexus).

I would love to be able to see/edit/refactor my local library files next to my Project1 (if it have the required snapshot version in gradle dependency) from AndroidStudio.
And in the same time, I need to be able to reproduce this setup on some other projects (eg Project2) and switch easily from one to the other.

**Is it event possible?**

Note: I have tried some configurations in settings.gradle to load a project from another URL but it implies dependency build each time, and it's not possible for me. I have also failed to use AS dependency system (I suppose it use gradle each time so it's not viable too).

Comment: If you're uploading the AAR to a local Nexus repo, you should be able to point to it via the `repositories` block in your build script and depend on it via its Maven coordinates there. You can either edit them as separate projects in separate windows, or you could have them both in the same project as two different modules, but don't set up cross-module dependencies between them so that they will build more independently.

Comment: Thanks @ScottBarta. AAR to Nexus: I'm ok with it for the build process. Edit them separately: ok too, but I have no good refactoring tools in this case (if I change a method in the lib, I have to open all other projects and fix it manually...). And have all in only one project looks not viable since we don't want multiple git submodules nor have to load all projects each time I want to make a fix on only one project.

So I understand that for you it's not possible, isn't it?

Do you think it's related to AndroidStudio or IntelliJ or gradle ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking for here. If you're doing refactoring of a commonly-used library, that's bound to cause a lot of pain regardless of how good your tools are.